# Is it safe to assume strict comparison in a JavaScript switch statement?

Tags: javascript, types, comparison, type-conversion, switch-statement

I have a variable that can either be boolean `false`, or an integer (including 0). I want to put it in a switch statement like:

```
switch(my_var){
    case 0:
         // Do something
         break;
    case 1:
         // Do something else
         break;
    case false:
         // Some other code
}
```

In my tests in Google Chrome, it seems to work perfectly, but I'm a little nervous to use it because I'm afraid that in some browsers, if `my_var` is `false`, it might execute the first case since `0 == false`.

I'm just wondering if there is anything official in JavaScript that says the switch statement will use strict comparison such that `0 !== false`, but I can't find anything myself, and I'm not sure if this will work well in different JavaScript engines. Does anybody know if the comparison done by a switch statement is guaranteed to be strict?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Take a look at [ECMA 262, section 12.11](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.11), the second algorithm, 4.c.

> *c.   If input is equal to clauseSelector as defined by the === operator, then...*

Comment: It's been [partying like that since 1999](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) (page 68, s. 12.11, CaseBlock #3)

Comment: Then... what? I'm not sure why you cut off the quote here.

Comment: That section looks like a bunch of gibberish; the other answers are a lot more helpful. I wonder why incomprehensible things like that get so many upvotes.

Answer (score 44):

http://qfox.nl/notes/110 answers your question. (This guy knows a lot about the nitty gritty of JavaScript)

> Switches in Javascript use strict type checking (===). So you never
>   have to worry about coercion, which prevents a few wtfjs :). If on the
>   other hand you were counting on coercion, tough luck because you can't
>   force it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/to469fLm/4/ , you could generalize the coercing function to achieve your needs

Answer (score 10):

Yes, `switch` "[uses] the strict comparison, `===`".

Source: [switch - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)