# JS Switch case not working correctly always default is executed

Tags: javascript, html, css, switch-statement

This is my drop down menu ---

```
<select name="category" id="category" onChange="showDiv(this.value);" >
    <option value="">Select This</option>
    <option value="1">Nokia</option>
    <option value="2">Samsung</option>
    <option value="3">BlackBerry</option>
    <option value="4">Spice</option>
    <option value="5">HTC</option>
    </select>
```

This is my  span class where i want to show the data on the basis of selection

```
<span class="catlink"> </span>
```

My JS Function (although the function is working fine when i am doing it through `if` conditions)

```
function showDiv(discselect) {
    switch(discselect) {
    case 1:
        document.getElementsByClassName("catlink")[0].innerHTML = '<a href="nokia.txt">Click To Download</a>';
        break;
    case 2:
        document.getElementsByClassName("catlink")[0].innerHTML = '<a href="samsung.txt">Click To Download</a>';
        break;
    case 3:
        document.getElementsByClassName("catlink")[0].innerHTML = '<a href="blackberry.txt">Click To Download</a>';
        break;
    default:
        alert(discselect);
        document.getElementsByClassName("catlink")[0].innerHTML = 'aaaa';
    }
}
```

Now on running the code each time the default case gets executed whereas 1,2,3 is still alerting, let me know what i am doing wrong and whr my logic lags??

Comment: please _don't repeat yourself_ !  Just evaluate `document.getElementsByClassName('catlink')[0]` _once_

Comment: [`switch...case` uses strict comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989902/is-it-safe-to-assume-strict-comparison-in-a-javascript-switch-statement?lq=1); you're comparing a string to an integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your discselect is coming across as a string..so you need to change your case to:

```
switch ( discselect ){
  case '1':
    break;
  case '2':
    break;
  case '3':
    break;
  default:
    alert(discselect);
  }
}
```

Comment: your shorter answer was better - no need to repeat the whole of the OP's code.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript's `case` tests are strict: if `discselect` is a string and not a number, your code will always take the default branch.

You can convert `discselect` to a number in your `switch` statement:

```
switch (+discselect) {
    // ...
}
```

Or use strings in your `case` tests:

```
switch (discselect) {
    case "1":
        // ...
        break;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: +1, but FWIW I'd go for `case '1'` since the `+` operator on the first selection would yield `0` which may cause confusion.

Comment: @Alnitak, true, I updated my answer with the alternate solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
onChange="showDiv(this.value);"
```

should be

```
onchange="showDiv(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)"
```

EDIT:
and

```
switch (discselect) {
```

should be

```
switch (+discselect) {
```

Comment: umm, no, they're (almost) equivalent.  If anything the latter is more error prone because `selectedIndex` can be -1

Comment: @Alnitak you're right. It solve nothing. but `switch(+discselect)` yes. I edit for complete answer (and +1ing to Frederic)