# javascript switch/case : are types compared?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it safe to assume strict comparison in a Javascript switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989902/is-it-safe-to-assume-strict-comparison-in-a-javascript-switch-statement)

Does a switch/case statement in javascript compare types or only values?

In other words, when I have the following code:

```
switch (variable)
{
    case "0": [...] break;
    case "1": [...] break;
    default: [...] break;
}
```

is it equivalent to

```
if ( variable == "0" )
{
    [...]
}
else if ( variable == "1" )
{
    [...]
}
else
{
    [...]
}
```

or to

```
if ( variable === "0" )
{
    [...]
}
else if ( variable === "1" )
{
    [...]
}
else
{
    [...]
}
```

edit: is there a way to force compare values and types at once?

Comment: You can easily test it...

Comment: Yes, it would have taken less time to type in a jsfiddle than it did to type in the question :-)

Comment: @amnotiam. How do you find them...? have you seen it before?

Comment: @gdoron: No, just did [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+switch+type+comparison). It's the first result. :)

Comment: @amnotiam, But this way you don't get reputation... `:)`

Comment: @gdoron Please compare the implications of "I tested it, it works on my machine" with "It's specified in the language." Pointing this out as a duplicate is a fair point, but "please save yourself the time and test it yourself" is not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, types are compared.

> If input is equal to clauseSelector as defined by the === operator,
>   then set found to true.

[ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), page 95.

Answer (score 1):

It checks types as well,

Example:

```
var x = false;

switch (x) {
case "":
    alert('x'); /// Not happening
    break;
case false:
    alert('y');  // happen
    break;
}​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y6cc3/1)

And as the spec says:

> If input is equal to clauseSelector as defined by the === operator, then...