# JavaScript switch-case internals

Tags: javascript, comparison, switch-statement

Consider the following code:

```
// Checking parities
switch(queueingSystem.Priority) {
    case 1: 
         FetchGridElements();
         break;
    case 1: 
         BindToControls(this, document.getElementsByClassName("grid-controls"));
         break;
    default:
         return false;
}
```

Is JavaScript internally testing value as well as type against each `case`, equivalent to:

```
queueingSystem.Priority === 1
```

Or

```
queueingSystem.Priority == 1
```

Comment: This is actually a good question. I think it depends from browser manufactors.

Comment: @reporter No, it's precisely specified in ECMAScript. See my answer.

Comment: Duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019104/javascript-switch-case-are-types-compared](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019104/javascript-switch-case-are-types-compared)

Comment: @dystroy, because I am working on Windows Store project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It checks the strict equality `===` as is demonstrated by this code :

```
switch (1) {
  case "1":
     console.log('ok');
     break;
  default :
     console.log('nok');
}
```

which logs `nok`.

It's defined in [the ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.11) :

> If input is equal to clauseSelector as defined by the === operator,
>   then

Comment: Thanks for the specifications link.

Answer (score 2):

Types are compared:

```
queueingSystem.Priority === 1
```