# Why switch and if statement in Javascript treat boolean different, confused

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I've got a switch and if problem in Javascript, the code is following.

```
var a=0;

if(a){
    console.log("a is true");
} else if(!a) {
    console.log("a is false");
} else {
    console.log("a is not true or false");
}


switch(a){
    case true:
        console.log("switch... a is true");
        break;
    case false:
        console.log("switch... a is false");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("switch... a is not true or false");
}
```

When I ran the code above, I got the result in console which confused me a lot:

```
a is false
switch... a is not true or false
```

I think it should be like this:

```
a is false
switch... a is false
```

Anyone knows why that happens? Very appreciate any answers.

Comment: Because in switch, it will look for the exact case matched!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it safe to assume strict comparison in a Javascript switch statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989902/is-it-safe-to-assume-strict-comparison-in-a-javascript-switch-statement)

Comment: Thank you very much, I will use switch more carefully from now on.

Answer (score 4):

If (!0) evalutes to true. Generally there is a rule anything non zero in if will evaluate to true an vie versa.

But for switch 0 will be explicitly checked against the case values and 0 is neither true or false , hence default statement gets executed.

Comment: Thank you very much, it makes sense, so we cannot use switch to replace if statement in some cases, right?

Comment: in general I would recommend not using switch statements for booleans.

Answer (score 1):

0 is neither true nor false, but it is !a

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, now I know switch uses === rule.

Answer (score 1):

[switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch): *The program first looks for a case clause with a label matching the value of expression and then transfers control to that clause.*

Since `a=0` doesn't match either of the cases: `true` or `false`. Hence `default` is executed.

[if-else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else): *Executes a statement if a specified condition is true. If the condition is false, another statement can be executed.*

Since `a=0` , so `!a` is true. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) is how the condition is evaluated.

Comment: Thank you very much, your explanation is very detailed, I think I should learn more basic stuff in Javascript.