# Changing var value from switch statement in a function

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have the following function, which, among other parameters, receives a parameter called pack_choice (which is a number). Depending on the number, I want to assign a text to var, and later print this var on canvas.

Here's the full function:

```
function create_voucher(visitor_name, unique_number, pack_choice)
{
var canvas = $("#canvas_voucher")[0];
var str_pack_name;

alert(pack_choice);

switch (pack_choice)
{
    case 1:
        str_pack_name = 'text 1';
        alert(str_pack_name);
        break;
    case 2:
        str_pack_name = 'text 2';
        alert(str_pack_name);
        break;
    case 3:
        str_pack_name = 'text 3';
        alert(str_pack_name);
        break;
}

alert(str_pack_name);

if (canvas.getContext)
{
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Draw shapes
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'images/voucher.jpg';

    img.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        ctx.fillStyle="#000000";

        ctx.font="bold 25px monospace";
        ctx.fillText(str_pack_name, 600, 120);

        ...draw name...

        ...draw number...
        draw_voucher_img();

        ...jQuery functions...
    }
} else {
    alert('Please update your browser');
}

}
```

The `alert(pack_choice);` does give me the passed number. But `alert(str_pack_name);` gives me `undefined` message in the alert and draws it on the canvas.

Why is it happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Is `pack_choice` being passed into the function as a `string` or an `integer`?

Comment: @Andy I think it's supposed to be `integer`, but now I'm not sure. The script is taking a value of a radio button `<input type="radio" value=3 name="pack" id="rb3">` as follows: `var int_pack_choice = $('input[name=pack]:checked').val();` and then the calls for that function: `create_voucher(str_visitor_name, unique_num, int_pack_choice);`. Is there any way to check if it's a string or an integer?

Comment: It's a string if you're getting it from an input. I'll add my answer to the list already there :)

Comment: `console.log(pack_choice)` should show up with quotes if it's a string.

Comment: Or `alert(typeof pack_choice);` I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your `switch case statements` to identify a string rather than a number:

```
switch (pack_choice) {
  case '1':
  case '2':
  case '3':
}
```

and that should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

As Andy said, pack_choice is probably a string, and the switch statement is not matching because it uses strict comparison (the types must match too). You can add this before the switch to force your variable into a number:

```
pack_choice = +pack_choice;
```

Another solution is to change your case statements to compare to strings, such as `case "1"`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
switch(parseInt(pack_choice))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `pack_choice = pack_choice * 1;` to cast it as an integer in the beginning of your function.

[`switch` uses strict equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989902/is-it-safe-to-assume-strict-comparison-in-a-javascript-switch-statement) according to another SO answer. Have not verified myself.