# JavaScript switch statement fails to match case

Tags: javascript

## I have the following problem to solve.

Problem 5. Digit as word

Write a script that asks for a digit (0-9), and depending on the input, shows the digit as a word (in English).
Print “not a digit” in case of invalid input.
Use a switch statement.
Examples:

```
digit   result
2       two
1       one
0       zero
5       five
-0.1    not a digit
hi      not a digit
9       nine
10      not a digit
```

=

Here's my JavaScript and HTML
HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="textInput">
<button id="react">Check</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

My JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){

   var input = document.getElementById('textInput');
   var button = document.getElementById('react');
   var result = document.getElementById('result');


   button.addEventListener('click',function(){

       switch (input.value) {
           case 0:
               result.innerHTML = 'zero';
               break;
           case 1:
               result.innerHTML = 'one';
               break;
           case 2:
               result.innerHTML = 'two';
               break;
           case 3:
               result.innerHTML = 'three';
               break;
           case 4:
               result.innerHTML = 'four';
               break;
           case 5:
               result.innerHTML = 'five';
               break;
           case 6:
               result.innerHTML = 'Six';
               break;
           case 7:
               result.innerHTML = 'Seven';
               break;
           case 8:
               result.innerHTML = 'Eight';
               break;
           case 9:
               result.innerHTML = 'Nine';
               break;
           default:
               result.innerHTML = 'not a digit';
               break;
       }

   });

});
```

The problem is that when I type a number from 0-9 it shows the default statement.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989902/is-it-safe-to-assume-strict-comparison-in-a-javascript-switch-statement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `value` is in string format. Convert it to number because `switch` statements do not coerce types (unlike `if` statements)

```
switch(+input.value) {
```

OR

```
switch(parseInt(input.value, 10)) {
```

---

I'll also suggest to use array or object.

```
var arr = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];

result.innerHTML = arr[+input.value] || 'Not a Digit';
```

Comment: Does input.value is always a string?

Comment: So if I set to <input type="number" id="inpuText"> , then my switch statement will works without having to parse it into a number?

Comment: @Nasco.Chachev No. ANYTHING that is read from the DOM is string. You've to manually convert it to number.

Comment: @Tushar oh , I didn't know that mate,  thank you a lot! in 10 minutes i`ll mark your answer as checked.Thank you for being so helpful!!!!

Comment: You can use[`input.valueAsNumber()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#property-valueasnumber)

Comment: That's interesting I thought `switch` would coerce types [but I was wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6989959/227299). From the EcmaScript standard: `If input is equal to clauseSelector as defined by the === operator, then...`  http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.11