# Switch statement not working correctly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have the following piece of code. For some reason the case statement that I don't want to execute (second for Case '2') is getting executing in addition to the correct one (Case '4'). After reading online it appears most ppl were able to resolve similar issue by adding a "break" statement. However it isn't working for me. Please advise.Output below is from my Browser

```js
var chk = '4'

switch (chk) {
  case '4':
    var locations = [
      ["936001_STURGEON_BAY_MEYER", 44.8358, -87.3305, "LRA", 1],
      ["936087_SHADOW_LAKE", 45.2183, -88.5981, "LRA", 2],
      ["936136_PIG", 44.5925, -88.0808, "OMS", 3],
      ["936136_PIG", 44.5925, -88.0808, "OMS", 4]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 15,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0][1], locations[0][2]),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      maxWidth: 400000
    });
    var locations_all_cells1 = locations;
    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations_all_cells1.length; i++) {
      var type1 = locations_all_cells1[i][3];

      switch (type1) {
        case "OMS":
          marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations_all_cells1[i][1], locations_all_cells1[i][2]),
            map: map,
            icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function(marker1, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(locations_all_cells1[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker1);
            }
          })(marker1, i));
          break;

        case "LRA":
          marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations_all_cells1[i][1], locations_all_cells1[i][2]),
            map: map,
            icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png'
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', (function(marker2, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(locations_all_cells1[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker2);
            }
          })(marker2, i));
          break;

        case "UPSAVE":
          marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations_all_cells1[i][1], locations_all_cells1[i][2]),
            map: map,
            icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png'
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'click', (function(marker3, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(locations_all_cells1[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker3);
            }
          })(marker3, i));
      }
    }
    break;

  case '2':
    var locations = [
      ["936001_STURGEON_BAY_MEYER", 44.8358, -87.3305, "LRA", 1],
      ["936087_SHADOW_LAKE", 45.2183, -88.5981, "LRA", 2],
      ["936136_PIG", 44.5925, -88.0808, "OMS", 3],
      ["936136_PIG", 44.5925, -88.0808, "OMS", 4]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 15,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0][1], locations[0][2]),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      maxWidth: 400000
    });
    var locations_all_cells = ;
    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations_all_cells.length; i++) {
      var type1 = locations_all_cells[i][3];
    }
    break;
    
  default:
    text = "Looking forward to the Weekend";
}
console.log(text);
```

Error Information

[image]

Comment: You haven't defined the `type1`! And I am definitely sure, this won't go to case 2... Or if it does go, make the `chk = '4';` as string.

Comment: In your code above only the default branch will be executed (neither case '2', nor case '4' will), because none of your cases match `4`. Note that `4 !== '4'`.

Comment: @Paulpro Does `switch` perform a strict check?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yeah, take a look at the forth question I asked on StackOverflow five years ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989902/is-it-safe-to-assume-strict-comparison-in-a-javascript-switch-statement haha

Comment: @Paulpro OMG, you are a celebrity!

Comment: Thanks to @PraveenKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally worked out my problem with help from a friend. It turns out Javascript does not like variables inside a case statement that are un-initialized. In one of the case statements  I was using a Variable to which I was assigning a value based on some logic before. Even though this case statement was not evaluated as "true" my program was throwing an error.

For example in the code below the program will error out for cases n and m if b is blank/null even though m is "false":

```
switch(expression) {
case n:
    break;
case m:
    Var a=b;
    break;
default:
    default code block
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [MDN Docs for `switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch):

> A switch statement first evaluates its expression. It then looks for the first case clause whose expression evaluates to the same value as the result of the input expression **(using strict comparison, ===)** and transfers control to that clause, executing the associated statements.

The `switch` performs a strict check, which doesn't match your `'4'` (string) and `4` (number). So you need to change your code like:

```
var chk = '4';
```

---

**Update**

If your browser is indeed loading it correctly, like `chk = '4'`, then it should work. See here:

```js
var chk = '4';
// Added this for checking.
var type1 = 'OMS';

switch (chk) {
  case '4':
    switch (type1) {
      case "OMS":
        text = "4 - OMS";
        break;
      case "LRA":
        text = "4 - LRA";
        break;
      case "UPSAVE":
        text = "4 - UPSAVE";
    }
    break;
  case '2':
    // ####Do some Stuff here##
    break;
  default:
    text = "Looking forward to the Weekend";
}
console.log(text);
```

Comment: @ssharma If your browser's code is indeed `chk = '4'`, then it should definitely work man. Can you post the right code please?

Comment: So I am actually getting value of the Variable chk  var chk = '<%= @tag %>'  by doing some other stuff in the background. I checked my browser and the output is indeed coming as var chk = '4'. Still No luck!

Comment: @ssharma Post the full code, that's rendered in the browser.

Comment: @ssharma See the above updated answer.

Comment: Please see the output from my browser. I have updated by original question.

Comment: @ssharma Checking it, seems like there are syntax errors. Did you notice them?

Comment: @ssharma `var locations_all_cells = ;` Syntax error dude.

Comment: @ssharma Did you see the syntax error? That's a **syntax error**! Please fix it.

Comment: in my code I have - var locations_all_cells = <%="ATall_cells_map%>; since the incorrect Case is executing the value of ATall_cells_map is not present... In my earlier code I only populate ATall_cells_map when chk = 2 which is not the case here. The value of chk is 4.

Comment: @ssharma Always enclose them inside `''`.