# Result order of Javascript concat method

Tags: javascript

Is the order of the concatenation result always preserved?

```
var alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var numeric = [1, 2, 3];

alpha.concat(numeric);
// result in ['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Downvotes but no one tries to explain whats wrong with the question? And no one casts a close vote? Weird ...

Comment: +1 from my side because it's a valid question but I would still like to recommend you to google out questions like these though since it's less of a debugging question and leads to opinionated answers and links.

Comment: @JonasW. This question is on-topic, clear and answerable, but it shows absolutely no research effort.

Comment: @xufox sure. Then why did the three downvoters not write this?! A downvote is a meaningless sign of ignorance

Comment: @JonasW. This reason is already covered in the tooltip on the downvote arrow: _“This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful”_.

Comment: @Xufox My most [upvoted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989902/is-it-safe-to-assume-strict-comparison-in-a-javascript-switch-statement) is very similar to this one. The answer can be paraphrased to "Yes, it says it here in the spec". It has had no downvotes to date. When I asked it in 2011 I had never even heard of ECMAScript and wouldn't have known where to look; that could very well be the case for this OP today. He's tried at least one test-case and got the result he expects. Now just wants to confirm that he can rely on that behaviour.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it is.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) (emphasis mine):

> The concat method creates a new array consisting of the elements in the object on which it is called, followed **in order** by, for each argument, the elements of that argument

From the [ECMAScript spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-array.prototype.concat) (emphasis mine):

> When the concat method is called with zero or more arguments, it returns an array containing the array elements of the object followed by the array elements of each argument **in order**.