# How to have alerts show within a switch

Tags: javascript

I have made a little test program to show the user what bonus they get from having a certain value. The case statements should function as an OR gate. But the problem shows up when the alert should show up on screen but does not.

I have changing a few values, but that did not work. Also new to using JavaScript so I do not know what I can do as of right now.

```
var strength = prompt("What is the value of strength?");

switch (strength) {
    case 10 : 
    case 11 : 
        alert("+0");
    break;

    case 12 : 
    case 13 : 
        alert("+1");
    break;

    case 14 : 
    case 15 : 
        alert("+2");
    break;

    case 16 :
    case 17 :
        alert("+3");
    break;

    case 18 :
    case 19 :
        alert("+4");
    break;

    case 20 :
    case 21 :
        alert("+5");
    break;

    default : ("Please enter a value between 10 and 20");
}
```

When the user enters the value of strength the bonus of that value should be showing up.

Example: `strength = 12 alert("+1")`
The alert does not show up though

Comment: well `"12" !== 12`

Comment: To add to what @epascarello is saying, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6989959/965834). In short, you'll have to convert your value to an integer first, or test (case) with strings.

Comment: The default is not showing an alert:  `default : ("Please enter a value between 10 and 20");` should be `default : alert("Please enter a value between 10 and 20");`

Comment: use `parseInt()` to convert prompt value to Integer

Answer (score 5):

Prompt returns a string and you are looking for numbers.

```js
var a = 10

switch (a) {
  case 10:
    console.log("a - yes");
    break;
  default:
    console.log("a - no");
}

var b = "10"

switch (b) {
  case 10:
    console.log("b - yes");
    break;
  default:
    console.log("b - no");
}
```

So either you change your switch to be strings, or you change your prompt to be a number. Many ways to do it.

```
var strength = Number(prompt("What is the value of strength?"));
var strength = parseInt(prompt("What is the value of strength?"));
var strength = +prompt("What is the value of strength?");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert `strength` to an integer:

```
var strength = parseInt(prompt("What is the value of strength?"));

switch (strength) {
    case 10 : 
    case 11 : 
        alert("+0");
    break;

    case 12 : 
    case 13 : 
        alert("+1");
    break;

    case 14 : 
    case 15 : 
        alert("+2");
    break;

    case 16 :
    case 17 :
        alert("+3");
    break;

    case 18 :
    case 19 :
        alert("+4");
    break;

    case 20 :
    case 21 :
        alert("+5");
    break;

    default : ("Please enter a value between 10 and 20");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare a string `strength` to an int value e.g:`10` and this is because prompt is reading as string.

quote from [w3schools:](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp)

> (Returns) a String. 
> If the user clicks "OK", the input value is returned.
>  If the user clicks "cancel", null is returned.
>  If the user clicks OK without entering any text, an empty string is returned.

What you can do is to use `parseInt()` function to convert the input to an int like so:

```
var strength = parseInt(prompt("your message: "));
```

Here's a short modified version:

```js
var strength = parseInt(prompt("What is the value of strength?"));

switch (strength) {
 case 11:
  console.log("11");
 break;

 case 12:
 case 13:
  console.log("+1");
 break;

 case 14:
 case 15:
  console.log("+2");
 break;
 default : ("Please enter a value between 10 and 20");
}
```