# How to target bootstrap carousel's active slide?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Evening,

Apologies for this likely being a really stupid question, I'm still learning!

I'm trying to target the active slide in the bootstrap carousel to perform an action. I'd like it to trigger some style changes for each of the three slides i.e. changing button colours etc.

Earlier I tried just targeting the divs by their numbers(`#1, #2, #3`), but kept getting stuck there too, it looked something like this;

```
var shead = document.getElementById("sub-head");
if ($('#1').is(':visible') && $('#2').is(':hidden') && $('#3').is(':hidden')) {   
    shead.style.color = "blue";
}
```

I repeated this for each of the slides using `:visible` & `:hidden` for each of the divs accordingly, although I only ever seemed to get stuck with the last presentation of the style colour change.

I did a some searching on this and I've seen people using `.carousel(1)`, but I just seem to keep hitting dead ends, can anyone give me a hand with this, not sure why it's not catching, any guidance would be appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<header id="Carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
       <div class="item active" id="1"></div>
       <div class="item" id="2"></div>
       <div class="item" id="3"></div>
    </div>

</header>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
if ($('#Carousel').carousel(1).hasClass('active')) {
    alert("this is an alert");
}
```

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: You can't start HTML `id` or `name` attributes with a number. Start the `id` with a letter instead of a number and see if that helps. ie `<div class="item active" id="c1">`

Comment: Take a close look at the following thread: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/2404#issuecomment-4589229

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Edit**: This answer was written for Bootstrap 3, but it should work for bootstrap 4 as well. See the following link for bootstrap 4 docs  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#events.

Bootstrap has custom events you can hook to.

This event will fire when the method is going to slide.

```
$('#Carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function onSlide (ev) {
  var id = ev.relatedTarget.id;
  switch (id) {
    case "1":
      // do something the id is 1
      break;
    case "2":
      // do something the id is 2
      break;
    case "3":
      // do something the id is 3
      break;
    default:
      //the id is none of the above
  }
})
```

There is also a `slid.bs.carousel` event. This event is invoked when the slider is finished sliding.

You can read about the differences here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#carousel-events.

P.S. note that `ev` is the event object that is passed to the `onSlide` callback when the event was triggered. Note that the name `ev` could have been changed to anything, for example `event`, it's the order of the parameter in the callback that determines its value not its name. Here the event object is passed in as the first parameter of the callback, this is due not to the above code having named the parameter accordingly `ev` (although that helps with understanding), but by how the jQuery code calls passed in event handlers (event handlers are a form of callback meant for events) and how the bootstrap code triggers the events. The event object has common properties to a [regular JavaScript event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#Properties), and it has the additional properties given here in [the bootstrap 4 docs for carousel events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#events) (with its current properties shown below as well in the yellow quote block).

> **direction**: The direction in which the carousel is sliding (either "left" or "right").
>   **relatedTarget**: The DOM element that is being slid into place as the active item.
>   **from**: The index of the current item.
>   **to**: The index of the next item.

Comment: Hi John,  this is exactly what I'm after, although I'm having some issues with the switch.
When I log the id value it's coming through correctly to the console, but I only seem to be hooking the default and not the case options, I'm not sure why as this seems sound to my limited experience.

Comment: It was because the data was not an integer, added a parse to solve as per;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099376/trouble-with-switch-javascript-always-executing-default-case

Thanks John, your input was much appreciated :)

Comment: @Sinden Yeah thanks for the feedback. Sorry I didn't originally check to see if the code with the id and the switch was right. I changed it and it should work now.  I decided to use strings instead of parseInt. This will make it easy to change even if the id is not just a number.

Comment: Amazing solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use the self bootstrap events parameters "from" and "to" to get the indexes like this:

```
var myCarousel = document.getElementById('#myCarousel')

    myCarousel.addEventListener('slide.bs.carousel', function (ev) {
        console.log(ev.from);
    })
```